# Why didn't anyone place Mjolnir on top of Thanos in Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, mjolnir, thanos

When Thor, Captain America, and Iron Man were fighting Thanos, it seems like one of the simplest ways to defeat him would have been to pin him with Mjolnir and then kill him with Stormbreaker. Of course, it's not an easy task, but Thanos was lying on the ground at one point, so it might have been possible.

It would have been particularly effective because Thanos did not have the Infinity Stones at this time, and it is established that the hammer cannot be lifted with brute strength. Hela seems to be an exception because she had some personal connection to the hammer. Also, Thanos can't even lift the hammer in the comics, where he's even stronger.

So why didn't Thor (or Captain America) use this technique, which worked against Loki and the dragon?

Comment: [Asked and answered over on movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/101356/45378).

Comment: Did not look there. Also it's hard to find a question when people downvote it to heck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Because they never actually get the chance to

Thanos is a good fighter, as evidenced by him holding his own against the Avengers (all except Wanda and Carol anyway) without the Infinity Stones. As such he knows not to lay on the floor for too long in a fight, even without getting pinned by Mjolnir it is a terrible idea and unless you are the Mountain you're probably not going to live for much longer.

This is true in the fight scene, he is constantly moving and the only times he really stays static are when the Avengers are all incapacitated. At one point he is on the floor after Steve called down lightning on him but when he attempts to strike Thanos he simply rolls out of the way.

In short they never tried it because they never got the chance to be able to try it.

Comment: I guess it's safe to assume Captain America would have left the hammer there if Thanos hadn't rolled away, thereby defeating him. Thanks